# Neo4j Relationships not showing connecting lines in the graph

Tags: neo4j

I created the following nodes and relationship in neo4j

```
CREATE (United_States:Citizenship { type : “Naturalized”})
CREATE (United_States:Citizenship { type : “Native_Born”})

CREATE (uid:Person { unique_id: 'A23AF39D-BEED-4FFC-B080-1362920FA7A8', id_type: '128bit_UUID' })

MATCH (uid:Person),(Native_Born:Citizenship) WHERE uid:Person="A23AF39D-BEED-4FFC-B080-1362920FA7A8" CREATE (uid) <- [ r:PersonUniqueIdentifier ] -> (Native_Born)

CREATE (fn:Person { first_name:'Willie', id_type:'128bit_UUID'})
CREATE (ln:Person { last_name:'Armstrong', id_type:'128bit_UUID'}))

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (uid:Person) ASSERT Person.unique_id IS UNIQUE

CREATE INDEX ON :Person(unique_id)
```

I do not see the 'PersonUniqueIdentifier' Relation between the Citizenship node and id:Person node on the graph.

[Screen shot of graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/02gzq4w1oij531j/Screenshot%202015-02-11%2019.25.28.png?dl=0)

Comment: you have a number of things going on here that i think are hanging you up.  Can you describe what your desired end state is?

Comment: Just want to see the Citizenship Node connect to the uid:Person node why is it not drawing the relationship properly?

Comment: you are matching the person, and two Citizenship nodes and then you are trying to create a bi-directional relationship between the two which can't be done; neo4j relationship are uni-directional only.  with your existing nodes still in the database try this... MATCH (p:Person), (nb:Citizenship { type : “Naturalized”}) CREATE p-[ r:PersonUniqueIdentifier ]->nb return *

Comment: MATCH (unique_id:Person), (Native_Born:Citizenship { type : 'Native_Born'}) CREATE (unique_id)-[ r:PersonUniqueId ]-> Native_Born return *    Thanks the missing * at the end also linked everything!

Comment: np. the asterisk just returns everything in the query. it was the fact that the relationship is uni-directional that allowed the relationship to be created so it could be returned.

Comment: I think you're mixing up labels `:Label` and node-identifiers in your statement, the identifiers are just like a variable and usually lower-case. You wouldn't create a `:Person` with identifiers `ln,fn or uid` as those are all attributes of the same Person.

Comment: I recommend you take the online training on neo4j.com/online-training to get up to speed with Cypher.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would make a habit of doing the indexes/constraints first.  There's not a lot of data here, but if you add an index after adding the data, it will need to go through all your nodes first.  Also, creating a constraint also adds an index for you, so no need for that line.  It seems like you're mixing up variables here, so refactoring a bit:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (person:Person) ASSERT person.unique_id IS UNIQUE
```

Also your `Citizenship` `CREATE`s are using the same variable name.  I don't know if that would necessarily cause a problem, but it's simpler to do this anyway:

```
CREATE (:Citizenship { type : “Naturalized”}), (:Citizenship { type : “Native_Born”})
```

This statement looks fine to me (though, again, you could lose the variable if you wanted to):

```
CREATE (person:Person { unique_id: 'A23AF39D-BEED-4FFC-B080-1362920FA7A8', id_type: '128bit_UUID' })
```

Here there are a few problems.  Here's how I would refactor it:

```
MATCH (person:Person),(citizenship:Citizenship)
WHERE
  person.unique_id="A23AF39D-BEED-4FFC-B080-1362920FA7A8",
  citizenship.type = 'Native_Born'
CREATE (person)-[:HAS_CITIZENSHIP]->(citizenship)
```

I'm not really sure what you want to do here.  It seems like you want to create one person, so I would do this:

```
CREATE (:Person { first_name:'Willie', id_type: '128bit_UUID', last_name:'Armstrong'})
```